# Wrong TV resolution for HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

I want to connect my laptop (Toshiba i5 with ATI drivers, I have proprietary ones installed) to my Sony KDL-32V2000 TV, which has a 1366x768 resolution.

The resolution of my laptop is also 1366x768. However, when I put the HDMI cable inside the laptop, the resolution of the laptop AND the TV switches to 1280x720.

From the Display settings, I have the "mirror displays" box ticked. There's no 1366x768 option in the resolution dropdown menu. How can I solve it?

Why are there these kinds of problems? I have read quite some questions about HDMI and external monitors problems. On Windows 7, I plug in the HDMI cable and it works. Why isn't this the case for Ubuntu (12.04) that I'm using?

Comment: have you looked for and/or used any other drivers?

Comment: Yes, the open source drivers. Things are even worse with them, I can't even connect to the external monitor :)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues - see [Display resolution problem with Sony TV and Intel integrated graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208060/display-resolution-problem-with-sony-tv-and-intel-integrated-graphics).
I think that there is something strange about this particular TV. I set the correct resolution using cvt and xrandr so the computer was set at the native resolution of the TV and I got a black screen. At 1920x1080 the edges are cut off. I think it is a TV issue, hopefully someone has a workaround