# Display resolution problem with Sony TV and Intel integrated graphics

Tags: display, intel-graphics, resolution

I am trying to set the correct display resolution for my Sony TV ([KDL-32V2000](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/tv-80-32-lcd/kdl-32v2000/technical-specifications#tab), native resolution 1366x768) connected via HDMI to my HTPC running Ubuntu 12.04. I have a Intel Core i3-530 and Intel mobo (DH57JG), so no proprietary graphics drivers.

The problem is that I can't get the correct resolution to display on the TV. Initially I only had 1024x768 (or similar) as a maximum resolution, which was not displayed properly. I tried a few steps, including generating an xorg.conf (initially didn't have one) and adding the segment as described in [this post](http://egopoly.com/archives/2006/01/mythtv_setup_fo.html) regarding this particular TV. I couldn't get this to work, and at this stage have reverted to running without an xorg.conf. Another post suggested upgrading to kernel 3.5, which did give me a 1920x1080 resolution option. This results in the TV cutting off a fair bit of the edges of the screen.

My Dell laptop with ATI drivers recognises the TV screen and works well via HDMI.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: also tried using cvt and xrandr, could not get this to work

Comment: Got cvt and xrandr to add correct modeline with TV's native resolution, but only got a black screen. I think its a TV overscan issue similar to this persons problem http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1890106

Answer (score 0):

That is a rather nonstandard looking resolution which might cause some difficulty, my guess would be that you would need a modeline in your xorg.conf for it, I just did some digging on this searching for xorg modeline 1366x768 and found a forum post which looks like it will probably help you out, the question there is also about configuring a mode for a TV.

Here is the link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1480033